# How to convert and display boolean value as a string value in winform datagrid cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, datagridview

I want to display the column value as `true` or `false` instead of checkbox as a column value in `DataGridView` in windows form application. Actually in database, the table has column `IsPaymentCard` which has value as `1` or `0` while binding the table value to `DataGridView`. In `DataGridView` the column value of `IsPaymentCard` is shown as a checkbox instead of `1` or `0`. I want to display the value as `boolean`.

I have tried as below

```
dataGridView1 .DataSource = wsobj.Get(connec,comand,"tablename");// binded through webservice

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["IsPaymentCard"].Value) == true)
    {
        row.Cells["IsPaymentCard"].Value = "True";
    }
    else row.Cells["IsPaymentCard"].Value = "False";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind Checkbox with Boolean value

```
        DataTable dtEmp = new DataTable();
        // add column to datatable  
        dtEmp.Columns.Add("IsPresent", typeof(bool));
        dtEmp.Columns.Add("EmpID", typeof(int));
        dtEmp.Columns.Add("EmpName", typeof(string));
        dtEmp.Rows.Add(true, 111, "ABC");
        dtEmp.Rows.Add(false, 444, "DEF");
        DataTable newDataTable = dtEmp.Clone();
        foreach (DataColumn dc in newDataTable.Columns)
        {
            if (dc.DataType == typeof(bool))
            {
                dc.DataType = typeof(string);
            }
        }
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtEmp.Rows)
        {
            newDataTable.ImportRow(dr);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = newDataTable;
```

Comment: Could u pls tell me what refers to dgvCmb in this code?

Comment: Could u pls tell me what refers to dgvCmb in your code? and i have tried this code.It is adding new coulmn to the datagridview with empty checkboxes and my column "ispaymentcard " still having checkboxes.But i need boolean value to be displayed.

Comment: It helps I got an output.Thank you Mnu

Comment: Is it possible to change the datatype of datagridview column programmatically in windows form applctn and the columns are "AutoGenerated".We can change the datatype of gridview coumn by using the "Edit Column" properties in the case of adding "Data source manually to gridview".But in my case i have added datasource to gridview programatically,So i can not change the column datatype through the properties.Your code changes the datatype of the data while fetching from the table.So it suits the gridview. Then how to change the coulmn datatype of gridview after fetching the data from source.

Comment: firstly convert your source data into datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RowDataBoundMethod to do this. In this method you can do something like following:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
        chk.Visible = false;
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = chk.Checked.ToString();
    }
}
```

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using BoundField column if not using autogeneratecolumn="true".

Change Columns to TemplateField as below.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# String.Equals(Convert.ToString(Eval("IsPaymentCard")).ToLower(),"true")?"true":"false" %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If you use like this, your foreach for dataGridView1.Rows not needed anymore.